# Using ifelse function by group

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
example.frame = data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
                           , "AL" = c(1,1,2,4,1,3,4,1,5,1,2)
                           , "marker" = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))
```

What I want to achieve is that for every `ID` group the `marker` variable is filled under the following condition. It is `1` for all rows following an `AL` of `5` or higher (in the row before) otherwise it is `0`. Does anyone has a suggestion how to solve it? I tried it with `by()` but the I do not know how to formulate the condition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't the last marker value be `0`, as the previous AL was 1?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea via base R, which assumes that there is only 1 value >=5 in each group,

```
with(example.frame, ave(AL, ID, FUN = function(i)
                                     replace(cumsum(i >= 5), i >= 5, 0)))

#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: they are looking for 5 or higher values

Comment: I think this solution still has two problems which you can see when changing the data to `example.frame$AL[10] <- 6`

Comment: @docendodiscimus The way I understood it is that there is only going to be 1 value >=5 in each group. I do however see your point, but since the OP accepted , I will leave it as is, until further comments from OP

Comment: I'll remove my downvote, but I don't see any indication in the OP that there can only be a single value >= 5 in each group. And in my opinion anyone should make their assumptions in an answer clear (since these are not only targeted at OP but also at future readers)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution with `ave` and `cummax`

```
example.frame$marker <- ave(example.frame$AL, example.frame$ID,
                            FUN=function(x) cummax(x >= 5))

example.frame
   ID AL marker
1   1  1      0
2   1  1      0
3   1  2      0
4   1  4      0
5   2  1      0
6   2  3      0
7   2  4      0
8   3  1      0
9   3  5      1
10  3  1      1
11  3  2      1
```

Or, if the goal is to start in the row after a 5 or greater is encountered, you could include `c` and `head` like this

```
ave(example.frame$AL, example.frame$ID, FUN=function(x) c(0, head(cummax(x >= 5), -1)))
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(example.frame)[, marker := +((cumsum(shift(AL >=5, fill=FALSE)))>0), ID]
example.frame
#    ID AL marker
# 1:  1  1      0
# 2:  1  1      0
# 3:  1  2      0
# 4:  1  4      0
# 5:  2  1      0
# 6:  2  3      0
# 7:  2  4      0
# 8:  3  1      0
# 9:  3  5      0
#10:  3  1      1
#11:  3  2      1
```

Comment: this will create values > 1 as soon as a second value >= 5 appears

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
example.frame = data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
                           , "AL" = c(1,1,2,4,1,3,4,1,5,1,2)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(marker = as.numeric(cummax(lag(AL, default = 0)) >= 5))

example.frame
```

Comment: They want all following marker values in that group to be 1

Comment: @docendodiscimus Oops, missed that nuance.  Added a `cummax` to compensate.